# Unexpected matlab operator?

Tags: matlab

I am writing a code (with MatLab) to produce Chebyshev polynomials. When n is equal to 0 and 1, this codes run perfectly. But for n=2 and larger, it gives me this error:

Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in myCheb (line 13)
        T(1,x) = 2*x*myCheb(n-1,x)-myCheb(n-2,x);

I would appreciate your help to figure out this problem.

My code is as below:

```
function [ T ] = myCheb( n,x )

out = zeros (1,size(x,2));

for i= 1:x
    if n==0
        T(1,x) = 1;
    elseif n==1
        T(1,x) = 2*x;
    else

        T(1,x) = 2*x*myCheb(n-1,x)-myCheb(n-2,x);
    end

end
out = T(1,x);
end
```

Comment: See: [`mtimes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html)  vs [`times`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html)

Comment: an example for input:   [T] = myCheb(2, 1:3)

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab the * operator defines a matrix multiplication.

Try changing line 13 to

T(1,x) = 2.*x.*myCheb(n-1,x)-myCheb(n-2,x);
 (note the full stops before the asterix)
this will do the multiplication element by element

http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html